# Array Rotation facing problems in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, rotation

Basically, I need to do this!
By inputting the rotating times = k, I want to make the array A[n+k] size.
As from the image if I input n=6 and rotating times, k =2, want to make the array A[8] and rest of the elements A[7] = 10 and A[8] =20
At last, want to move the elements per room (right to left from the index 3).
[https://imgur.com/a/qA9aM5P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU2oC.png)

Tired in Codebooks but got an error when I put n = 10 and k = 7

```
int main(){
int n, k;
    cout<<"Array Size: ";
    cin>>n;

    int a[n];

    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        cin>>a[i];

    cout<<"Rotate (k): ";
    cin>>k;

    a[n+k];

    for(int i = 1; i<=k; i++)
    {
        a[n+i] = a[i];
    }

    for(int j = 1; j<=n; j++)
    {
        a[j] = a[k+j];
        cout<<a[j]<<endl;
    }
}
```

if I input n = 10 and k = 7 and the arrays are 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

I expect the rotation like this: 8 9 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: Have a look at std::rotate: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Comment: `a[n+k];` I think you expect this will resize the array. It will not. However, you can rotate an array without resizing it. Store the value in the last index. Move everything right 1. Put stored value at index 0. Repeat.

Comment: You need to access the array you instantiate in `int a[n]`.  The statement `a[n+k]` just accesses an element that is out of bounds for `a[]`.  Have you tried using modulus (`%`)?

Comment: `int a[n];` is not standard c++ for a non compile time constant `n`. Use `std::vector` if you need dynamic size

Comment: "Store the value in the last index" in which index?
Suppose, if I input n = 10, and k = 7(Here k = hows many elements I want to rotate). Then how I store these 7 values?

Comment: You want to swap elements in the array (e.g. `a[i + (x)] = a[i]`).

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n, k,input;
cout<<"Array Size: ";
cin>>n;

vector<int>a; 

for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    cin>>input;
    a.push_back(input);
}
cout<<"Rotate (k): ";
cin>>k;

for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
{
     rotate(a.begin(), a.begin() + 1, a.end());
}
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout<<a[i]<<endl;
}

return 0;
}

One problem was initializing the array was wrong. Since you start at index 0. 
In order to do this function, we need to right rotate k times.
```

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not part of C++.

Answer (score 0):

[SL.con.1: Prefer using STL array or vector instead of a C array](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rsl-arrays). Also C++ does not support variable-length arrays like

```
int n;
std::cin >> n;
int a[n];
```

So you should use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Also [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) already exists. Using both you can solve your problem like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    int n, k;
    std::cout << "Array Size: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> a(n);

    for(auto &el : a)
        std::cin >> el;

    std::cout << "Rotate (k): ";
    std::cin >> k;

    std::size_t rotation = k >= 0 ? (k % a.size()) : a.size() - (-k % a.size());

    std::rotate(std::begin(a), std::begin(a) + rotation, std::end(a));

    for(const auto &el : a) {
        std::cout << el << '\n';
    }
}
```

The range-based for loop solves the index problem in your for loop.